# ERROR: Invalid record ID. Specify valid record ID value

Tags: salesforcedx, ci

I have set up Travis CI based on the salesforce trailhead for it, I have used the  .travis.yml file, completed the steps. However, when the Travis CI tries to create a scratch org

`(sfdx force:org:create -v HubOrg -s -f config/project-scratch-def.json -a ciorg)`

I constantly get the following:

> ERROR:  Invalid record ID. Specify valid record ID value.

In my local files, this works perfectly fine.

EVEN more weird it randomly got past this point (timed out when pushing) but now it is failing at this point again.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:
I signed in to my dev hub org manually in another tab and then ran the build in travis ci again and it got past the above error